# typescript return inferred type of assigned function, yet restrict the return type to extend predefined type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing many functions(for server requests), each of the function return type extends a certain type.
I want typescript to restrict the return type to extend a  predefined known type but yet I want typescript to take the inferred type of the return type(because it is possibly more accurate).

for example, lets say all functions must return string, so:

```js
type myFuncsType = (...args: any) => string
```

each function must extend this type.

now lets say my function always returns a constant string:

```js
const myFunc1 = () => "MyString" as const
// the type is inffered:
const myVal = myFunc1()
// typeof myVal = "MyString"
```

we also said that our functions must extend predefined known type(`myFuncsType`), but when assigning the type, the general type takes over the inffered accurate type, and this something i want to avoid:

```js
const myFunc1: myFuncsType = () => "MyString" as const
const myVal = myFunc1()
// typeof myVal = string
```

I tried solving it with generics, but generics require to pass predefined type, and the return type is not available during the declaration.

how can I restrict return type to extend predefined type but yet return the exact return type that was inferred from the declaration?

Comment: Could you add a fuller example of the scenario where you would have to use `myFuncsType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MyFuncsType` is not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), if you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the `myFunc1` variable with that type, the compiler will always see that variable as being of that type.  It does not [*narrow*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) the variable based on the specific value assigned to it, but instead *widens* it all the way to the annotated type.  So you do not want to annotate `myFunc1`.

Instead of annotating, all you really want to do is *check* that `myFunc1` is assignable to `MyFuncsType`, without widening it.  There is no built-in operator to do this in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) for a request for such a feature.  But you can write your own helper function which behaves this way:

```
type MyFuncsType = (...args: any) => string
const asMyFuncsType = <T extends MyFuncsType>(t: T) => t;
```

So in place of `const f: MyFuncsType = ...`, you write `const f = asMyFuncsType(...)` instead.  The `asMyFuncsType()` function just returns its input without changing its type, but it does check that the type is assignable to `MyFuncsType`, so it will catch errors:

```
const badFunc = asMyFuncsType(() => 123); // error!
// -------------------------------> ~~~
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

const myFunc1 = asMyFuncsType(() => "MyString" as const); // okay
const myVal = myFunc1()
// typeof myVal = "MyString"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYwM4BVzQLxQAoA6EgQwCcBzdALilORAEopcA+KdYcgS2UoBQqAPbIu9dHCRosOVlAA8mKBAAewCMgAm6WAhQZskNgWB1MLdlGABuAUNHiARqS3TU80pP0yjEAgSWHACMAEwAzEw2UAD0MSrk5MLkAIQCcVAAtNk5uXn5BTkcAH6l6fF+UADkyIgAtk4Q5FVQPLrIwsAS6DyUyKROADbQwMLWclVcvPxV9iJiXXU+qMGe3u6ykAFBUABEcADK3HyUuxJQ81xRsfHCANakIA4LUEsAaqSD8kvuwYHl40gwgAZq8QB8vvh9iAjtNTvYgA)

Comment: this is a great workaround, thanks! yet this is quite annoying because this has runtime consequences. still great answer

Comment: Update: The mentioned feature has been implemented in TypeScript 4.9: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator

Answer (score 0):

> We can have a return type of the function available during the declaration.

You could use one of the in-built typescript utility `ReturnType`. This utility provides the return type of the function type. You can read more examples of the `ReturnType` utility [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype).

```
type myFuncsType = (...args: any) => string
type FnReturnType = ReturnType<myFuncsType>;
```

> **Your question**: How can I restrict return type to extend predefined type but yet return the exact return type that was inferred from the declaration?

Let's know what is the difference between the extended type (or assigned type) and type assertion first.

```
const a: any = 20;
const b = a as number;
// typeof b is number
```

*When we assign the type to our variable, the typescript knows and confirms that what type it will come for that variable.*

*We do [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) when we have information about the type of value that TypeScript can’t know about.*

So, while coming to your question, there is no point in having both assigned type and type assertion of the same value. If you want to do that typescript will say I know more about the type than you.